¿Como ejecuto una funcion de pl sql que retorna valor desde c#?
nesecito usar esta funcion de pl sql
create or replace FUNCTION fn_AbrirTurno( hor TURNOS.horario%TYPE, fec TURNOS.fecha%TYPE, saldo TURNOS.saldo_inicial%TYPE, cajero TURNOS.id_empleado%TYPE, es TURNOS.estado%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    id_turn TURNOS.id_turno%type;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TURNOS(horario, fecha, saldo_inicial, id_empleado, estado)
    VALUES (hor, fec, saldo, cajero, es);

    SELECT sq_IdTurnos.NEXTVAL INTO id_turn FROM dual;

    RETURN id_turn;
END;

actualmente en c# la intento usar así
    public Turno  AbrirTurno(Turno turno)
    {
        oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("FN_ABRIRTURNO");
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oracleCommand.Connection = Conexion();
        AbrirConexion();

        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("hor", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = turno.Horario;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("fec", OracleDbType.Date).Value = turno.Fecha;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("saldo", OracleDbType.Long).Value = turno.SaldoInicial;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("cajero", OracleDbType.Long).Value = turno.Cajero.Id;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("es", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = turno.Estado;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        // fn_AbrirTurno( hor TURNOS.horario%TYPE, fec TURNOS.fecha%TYPE, saldo TURNOS.saldo_inicial%TYPE, cajero TURNOS.id_empleado%TYPE, es TURNOS.estado%TYPE)
        // Ejecuta el procedimiento


        // Ejecuta la función
        oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Obtén el valor devuelto por la función
        turno.Id = Convert.ToInt64(oracleCommand.Parameters["return_value"].Value);

        CerrarConexion();
        return turno ;
    }


Y ¿qué es tu pregunta? ¿Funciona tu código o no? Si no funciona, ¿qué pasa? ¿Pasa nada o recibes un mensaje de error o ...?
